# Get single digit time in python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

I am using following code to get current time in python.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
message_sent_time = now.strftime("%I:%M %p")
```

It returns time as

```
06:58 PM
```

However, I would like to get output as

```
6:58 PM
```

i.e. single digit time when time is before 10. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a single-digit hour using `%-I`:

```
>>> message_sent_time = now.strftime("%-I:%M %p")
>>> print(message_sent_time)
7:07 PM
```

Full `strftime` formatting reference: http://strftime.org/

Comment: Invalid string format on Windows :c

Comment: The `strftime` doc referenced in my answer does mention that `%-I` is platform-specific. This may be what they meant.

Comment: Try a `#` instead of a dash. As in: `%#I`.